# Ansible expect adds other character to response and does not enter it

Tags: ansible, pexpect

I'm trying to install [no-ip's Dynamic Update Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xp4kkbsZi0). I'm using the [expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) to answer every prompt, but each time the script ask for my password, it adds another character and does not enter the password (the `command exceeded timeout`).

Here is my task (`noip_email` and `noip_password` are variables from a vault. I tried printing them and they are correct).

```yaml
- name: DNS - install no-ip DUC
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: "make install"
    chdir: /usr/local/src/noip
    echo: true
    responses:
      "By typing the number associated with it": "0"
      "login/email": "{{ noip_email }}"
      "password": "{{ noip_password }}"
      "update interval": "20"
      "run something": "n"
```

I tried to simplify the matching word; using the full sentence; not using variables (from a vault); I tried not to match output ([see the second example in ansible's doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#examples)), tried a bigger timeout, and also tried adding manual "enter" with `\n` at the end of the prompt.

None of the solution I tried or found on the internet worked, and I ran out of ideas. I really don't know why it adds another character to the **password** input, and why it doesn't enter (`\n`) my password, especially when every other prompt is correct and entered.

**System:**

- Ansible 2.13.5
- Python 3.10
- Ubuntu 22.04, Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb

Comment: My guess is that the password is encrypted with ansible-vault? could it be that the value encrypted has the extra-character? if you print the value with `debug`, does the extra character appear?

Comment: No, i've tried that, and it prints the good password. Also, I tried putting a single char, and it always ends up with 2 '*' for the password

Comment: I've been unable to replicate the issue, could you give us more detail of the steps, environment (like the ansible version used)?

Comment: of course, i'm using Ansible 2.13.5 with python 3.10. I'm trying to install this on a raspberry pi 8Gb, with Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue by using the `expect` binary with the `shell` module.

```yaml
- name: DNS - install no-ip DUC
  ansible.builtin.shell: |
    set timeout 30
    spawn make install

    expect "number associated"
    send "0\n"

    expect "email"
    send "{{ noip_email }}\n"

    expect "password"
    send "{{ noip_password }}\n"

    expect "update"
    send "20\n"

    expect "run"
    send "n\n"
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
    chdir: /usr/local/src/noip
```